# unexpected syntax error on 'else' while the code seems correct

Tags: python-2.7, if-statement

```
def restudy():
    print "OK, since you decided to restudy at MIANYANG high school, you must work hard!"
    print '''
    Now, it's time to determine your destiny.
    Please answer the questions below:
    what's the result of 1+1? 
    if you give the right answer, you can go to Shanghai; but if you can't
    you'll be caught in here forever.
    '''

    test = raw_input("> ")

    if test == "2":
        print "you succeed!"
        shanghai()
    else: # that's the error line
        restudy()
```

And that's the result terminal shows to me:

> ```
>  else:
>         ^
>  SyntaxError: invalid syntax
> ```

what's the problem about my code? cuz I think it seems right.
hope someone could help me out.
thanks!

Comment: Make sure you're using consistent tabs or spaces for indentation.

Comment: I can't reproduce the error. It's probably inconsistent whitespace characters.